# Python pandas: Weird index value

Tags: string, indexing, using, covariance

I have posted a similar thread but have now another angle to explore: After doing a covariance analysis between X and Z groupby 2 different levels, I get a DF like

```
index       X      Z

(1,1,'X')  2.3     0
```

...

'1' and '1' are the 2 different levels (I could have chosen '1' and '2'; there are 5 and 10 different levels)
Now I would like to extract each 'element' of the index and have something

```
 index       X      Z     H1      H2     H3

(1,1,'X')  2.3     0      1       1      X
```

...

I read few posts on slice and dice things - but this is not a normal string is it? 
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1,1,'X') isn't a string here, It's a tuple.

So you need to split the tuple into multiple columns. You can achieve this

by using apply(pandas.Series)

say your dataframe was df in this case.

```
df.apply(pandas.series)
In [10]: df['index'].apply(pd.Series)
Out[10]:
0  1  2  3
0  1  1 'X'
```

You need to add the columns back to original data frame so

```
df[['H1', 'H2','H3']] = df.apply(pandas.Series)
```

Comment: I can see a faint light at the end of the tunnel already. as you might have guessed I'm new to this.

Comment: when I run 
import pandas pd
df.apply(pd.series)   I get a 'module pandas has no attribute series. Should I import series as well?

Comment: SOLVED!!! slight mistake on my part for the last stretch. many thanks TheManhasNoName. magic!